# How to clear all active job queues before test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activejob

I have the following test:

```
class ModelTest < ActiveJob::TestCase
  test 'test somethingb' do
    # test
  end
end
```

and I would like, if possible, to clear all queues before any test. Something like:

```
class ModelTest < ActiveJob::TestCase
  before_each do
   Sidekiq::Worker::clear_all
  end

  test 'test somethingb' do
    # test
  end
end
```

Which of course does not work. I didn't find much information on googling around. Is that possible? If so, how to?

Answer (score 0):

Directly from the sidekiq [docs](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Testing).

To clear all workers' jobs:

```
Sidekiq::Worker.clear_all
```

To make sure jobs don't linger between tests:

```
module SidekiqMinitestSupport
  def after_teardown
    Sidekiq::Worker.clear_all
    super
  end
end

class MiniTest::Spec
  include SidekiqMinitestSupport
end

class MiniTest::Unit::TestCase
  include SidekiqMinitestSupport
end
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `test/test_helper.rb` add `require 'sidekiq/testing'`

In your test `before_each` callback, add `Sidekiq::Worker.clear_all`